# Errors while installing SQL Server SSIS 2005

Tags: installation, sql-server

I was trying to use SQL Server SSIS 2005 for the first time and mysteriously all the SQL SSIS menu items were missing from my start menu and then from the BIDS project choices even though I did a full install of SQL 2005 Pro. I read that if you have SQL Express installed before you install SQL Pro (or > Express) then you need to uninstall everything for SSIS to install properly.. I had Express on before.. I do this and reboot. I try to re-install SQL 2005 Pro and I get errors all over the place, starting with MSXML6 failed to install.

I read about this and it is suggested that I need to uninstall MSXML6 before installing SQL -  then I try to uninstall and I get an error (`installation failed`) when I am trying to uninstall it. Then I find [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ffa396d8-fafe-4c3c-bbba-415749ad875e)  which says I need to use a `Windows Cleanup tool` .I do some more reading and it appears the Windows cleanup tool has been retired.

TLDR: I was happy using SQL 2005 and tried to get SSIS running now nothing works. can anyone help?

Comment: Please avoid ranting all over SO.

Comment: And when this gets migrated, clean it up. The StackExchange sites are a place to ask questions that will be useful to other people, not an internet forum for (understandably) frustrated rantings.